# AngularJS - disable if $pristine bug for inputs with pre-filled ng-model values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input field that is pre-filled with a value from an object's json property using ng-model, and I'm trying to disable a button if this input is either empty **initially** or if it has an invalid value.

This works, but when the page loads with data already in the input box as a value, the input is treated as being $pristine, because it has not been touched, even though there is a valid value. Therefore, the button, which should be enabled because of the valid value, is still disabled.

I can change the $pristine condition to (personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$pristine && personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$invalid), which correctly enables the button on load when there is a pre-filled value in the input, but if the pre-filled value is removed, the input isn't treated as being invalid.

Is there any way around this?

HTML:

```
<div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
    <input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" pattern=".{9}" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="niNumber">
    <label for="niNumberInput" data-error="National Insurance number must be 9 characters long">National Insurance Number</label>
</div>
<div input-field class="input-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1">
    <button data-ng-click="verifyNINumber()" data-ng-disabled="personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$invalid || personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$pristine" class="btn button waves-effect"><span class="fa fa-search"></span>Verify</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm terrible with && and || evaluations ... but maybe use && instead of ||?

Comment: you don't have to check if it is `$pristine`, just remove that kind of check. `if form is $valid THEN send it`.

Comment: @Nick Can you please explain what `pattern=".{9}"` this pattern does, I am not good with regex!

Comment: Nothing to do with form submission, it's about trying to dynamically enable or disable a button before the form is submitted. The 'verify' button is not the submit button for the form

Comment: @Naren Murali - It makes the input valid only if the length of input is exactly 9 characters

Answer (score 0):

You can add another check to make sure the form is invalid at the same time as being pristine.
This way, the button is disabled if the form is invalid, OR if the form is pristine but invalid at the same time.

`ng-disabled=personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$invalid || (personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$pristine && personalDetailsForm.niNumber.$invalid)`

Comment: This still results in the button being enabled if all the pre-filled value is removed

Comment: Add a condition to ng-disabled that `niNumber === ''`? That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `pattern` attribute's regex does not handle empty input field, hence the button is enabled, If you add the `required` attribute in the element its working fine.

**Before:**

```
<input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" 
pattern=".{9}" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="niNumber">
```

**After:**

```
<input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" 
pattern=".{9}" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="test" required>
```

Also please use a different variable name for `ng-model` its better if its not the same as the element name. The fix for the question is to add the `required` attribute which will check the empty input element, which is not handled by `ng-pattern`.

**Alternate Solution (Recommended):**

```
<input id="niNumberInput" name="niNumber" type="text" class="validate" 
ng-maxlength="9" ng-minlength="9" placeholder="{{niNumber}}" data-ng-model="test" required>
```

The above code does the same job as your regex, but its uses only angular validation and its much easier to understand :p

Please find below a demo of the solution.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @Nick does this help you?